# Dúvida para remover atributos JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Dado o seguinte objeto:

```
var pessoa = {
    nome: 'Fernando',
    idade: 15,
}
```

Gostaria de saber qual o jeito mais CORRETO(se é que existe um jeito mais correto) de se remover um desses atributos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode usar o [operador delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete):

```js
var pessoa = {
    nome: 'Fernando',
    idade: 15,
};

// verifica se nome existe
if (pessoa.nome)
 delete pessoa.nome;

console.log(pessoa);
```

Comment: Hmmm, entendi. Mas existe algum jeito correto?? Ou não tem isso?

Comment: Eu não conheço outra forma de remover uma chave de um objeto além do delete. Se não tiver certeza quando se a chave existe, seria interessante usar `pessoa['nome'];`. Essa é a forma padrão.

Comment: Um amigo falou pra eu fazer "pessoa.idade = undefined". Isso tá certo?? Pode trazer algum problema?

Comment: Isso é para verificar se o atributo existe. Se você quiser verificar se ele existe antes de deletar por exemplo, é possível fazer: `if (pessoa.idade) delete pessoa.idade`. O que acontece aqui, é que ele só vai deletar se existir.

Comment: Nem precisa verificar se existe, o delete só vai lançar exceção se a a propriedade não for deletável (e ainda assim só propriedades customizadas, não-nativas).

Comment: @fernandoocf O seu amigo te falou para mudar o valor da propriedade para undefined. Isso é diferente de remover a propriedade do objeto, só remove o valor.

Comment: Obrigado! @bfavaretto